# A mix of Type-1 and 2 conditionals

Tags: conditionals

I found this sentence as an example of usage of would on britannica.com

**If we invite him, Adam would visit us on Monday.**

Normally we are taught to write if we ever get a Type-1 conditional as

If we invite him, Adam will visit us on Monday

Or if it is unlikely to invite him, we write it in Type-2 conditional as

If we invited him, Adam would visit us on Monday.

But the sentence I found is written in sort of mixture of Type-1 and 2 conditionals.

Is it giving the sense that the probability of inviting him is good but the possibility of Adam's visiting  on Monday is very little?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example where, **as in some many cases**, dividing conditional forms into "type 1", "type 2", and "type 3" is misguided and unhelpful. Those "typed" simply do not capture all valid and commonly used conditional forms.

The sentence

> If we invite him, Adam would visit us on Monday.

is perfectly acceptable and might well be spoken or written by a fluent or native speaker of English.

> Is it giving the sense that the probability of inviting him is good but the possibility of Adam's visiting on Monday is very little?

No, quite the reverse.

This sentence suggests that if the invitation is issued, it is reasonably certain that Adam will visit, but the invitation is not at all assured.

In contrast:

> If we invite him, Adam will visit us on Monday.

suggests a  somewhat lower degree of doubt about the invitation. However, many fluent speakers will treat these two sentences as interchangeable, with no difference of meaning.