# would burst if you continue/continued to fill

Tags: conditional-constructions, conditionals

Traditional grammar teaches that "would V" is paired with a superficial past tense in conditional sentences of type (b). But nothing is said about sentences like (a), where modal "would" is paired with a present tense verb in the if-clause. If both sentences are okay, what does (a) mean, and how does it differ from (b)?

> a. I think the balloon **would** burst if you **continue** to fill it with air.

> b. I think the balloon **would** burst if you **continued** to fill it with air.

Comment: Why do you think "would" is superficially past tense? Do you mean because it refers to the present time, in contrast to places where "would" refers to the past time?

Comment: @gotube Yes, it is specifically used in counterfactual sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentence a. is not grammatical. Conditional expressions include a condition and a result, and the two parts must either be both real or both unreal (technically, *realis* or *irrealis*, what you call "counterfactual" in the comments), not a mix of the two.

With "would burst" in the past form, the result is unreal. But with "continue to fill it with air" in present form, the condition is "real". A real condition cannot lead to an unreal result.

You can mix almost any two tenses to create your own conditional expression, but it's basically impossible to mix real and unreal and end up with something grammatical.

Comment: Can't the "would" in sentence (a) be thought of as a deductive usage, as in "Who's ringing the doorbell? It'd be John"?

Comment: @Apollyon No. There's no deduction here, just observation and prediction. The closest I can get is something like, "I'd think the balloon will burst", meaning, "If you asked me, I would say the balloon will burst".

Comment: I've found this sentence on the Free Dictionary website: We **would** also omit the comma if another parenthetical element (such as an appositive or absolute phrase) using em dashes **appears** directly after the country or state...

Comment: Do you fiind it ungrammatical too?

Comment: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Commas.htm#Parenthetical%20information

Comment: @Apollyon Yes, it's ungrammatical, though a fairly common mistake for native speakers. If I'm not being careful, and I'm creating the sentence as I say it, I might say something like that.

Comment: Is it a mistake in a prescriptive or descriptive sense?

Comment: @Apollyon Descriptive. You'll never catch me enforcing prescriptive rules.

Comment: Somehow many natives don't see anything wrong with it, so I thought it was a prescriptive error.

Comment: @Apollyon It's very minor, to be sure, but it's incorrect.

Comment: @gotube I asked a very similar question around a year ago and I was told that it is a correct usage.  Can you please check it out and give your opinion? Here is the link of that question https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/313110/129187

Comment: @RADS It's incorrect, and in a language assessment test, it would be marked wrong. A native speaker might say it that way in unprepared speech, but in writing or in prepared speech they'd correct it. If you asked that speaker whether they meant the sentence to be real or unreal, they wouldn't be able to answer. A conditional simply cannot meaningfully be both real and unreal.